# Fluentbit Kubernetes - How to extract fields from existing logs

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, kibana, fluent-bit

I have configured EFK stack with Fluent-bit on my Kubernetes cluster. I can see the logs in Kibana.

I also have deployed nginx pod, I can see the logs of this nginx pod also in Kibana. But all the log data are sent to a single field "log" as shown below.

[image]

How can I extract each field into a separate field. There is a solution for fluentd already in this question. [Kibana - How to extract fields from existing Kubernetes logs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42270621/kibana-how-to-extract-fields-from-existing-kubernetes-logs)

But how can I achieve the same with fluent-bit?

I have tried the below by adding one more FILTER section under the default FILTER section for Kubernetes, but it didn't work.

> ```
> [FILTER]
>     Name                parser
>     Match               kube.*
>     Key_name            log
>     Parser              nginx
> ```

From this (https://github.com/fluent/fluent-bit/issues/723), I can see there is no grok support for fluent-bit.

Comment: which parser are u using , ? it should fit on some parser https://github.com/fluent/fluent-bit-kubernetes-logging/blob/master/output/elasticsearch/fluent-bit-configmap.yaml

Comment: i am using the same kubernetes filter which is there in your link, but my app logs are pumped into a single field called "log", i want to do one more filter and extract the fields from the single field.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In our official documentation for Kubernetes filter we have an example about how to make your Pod suggest a parser for your data based in an annotation:

https://docs.fluentbit.io/manual/filter/kubernetes

Comment: thank you it is working.. i read the documentation earlier but didn't understand the purpose earlier.. may be a simple article might help many people in this regarding..

Comment: The link is 404 now.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this configmap:

https://github.com/fluent/fluent-bit-kubernetes-logging/blob/master/output/elasticsearch/fluent-bit-configmap.yaml

The nginx parser should be there:

```
[PARSER]
        Name   nginx
        Format regex
        Regex ^(?<remote>[^ ]*) (?<host>[^ ]*) (?<user>[^ ]*) \[(?<time>[^\]]*)\] "(?<method>\S+)(?: +(?<path>[^\"]*?)(?: +\S*)?)?" (?<code>[^ ]*) (?<size>[^ ]*)(?: "(?<referer>[^\"]*)" "(?<agent>[^\"]*)")?$
        Time_Key time
        Time_Format %d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S %z
```

Comment: i have this parser in my configmap, but seems like multiple filtering feature is not yet available in fluent-bit "https://github.com/fluent/fluent-bit/issues/483"